# Python: how to multiply 2 columns?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the simple dataframe and I would like to add the column 'Pow_calkowita'. If 'liczba_kon' is 0, 'Pow_calkowita' is 'Powierzchn', but if 'liczba_kon' is not 0, 'Pow_calkowita' is 'liczba_kon' * 'Powierzchn. Why I can't do that?

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['liczba_kon'] == 0:
        row['Pow_calkowita'] = row['Powierzchn']
    elif row['liczba_kon'] != 0:
        row['Pow_calkowita'] = row['Powierzchn'] * row['liczba_kon']
```

My code didn't return any values.

```
    liczba_kon  Powierzchn
0            3    69.60495
1            1    39.27270
2            1   130.41225
3            1   129.29570
4            1   294.94400
5            1    64.79345
6            1   108.75560
7            1    35.12290
8            1   178.23905
9            1   263.00930
10           1    32.02235
11           1   125.41480
12           1    47.05420
13           1    45.97135
14           1   154.87120
15           1    37.17370
16           1    37.80705
17           1    38.78760
18           1    35.50065
19           1    74.68940
```

I have found some soultion:

```
result = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['liczba_kon'] == 0:
        result.append(row['Powierzchn'])
    elif row['liczba_kon'] != 0:
        result.append(row['Powierzchn'] * row['liczba_kon'])
df['Pow_calkowita'] = result
```

Is it good way?

Comment: You seem to be trying to modify the data in place while iterating over it. See https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html which quotes "You should never modify something you are iterating over". `iterrows()` appears to return copies of each row, not the actual rows themselves

Answer (score 1):

To write idiomatic code for Pandas and leverage on Pandas' efficient array processing, you should avoid writing codes to loop over the array by yourself.  Pandas allows you to write succinct codes yet process efficiently by making use of vectorization over its efficient numpy ndarray data structure.  Underlying, it uses fast array processing using optimized C language binary codes.  Pandas already handles the necessary looping behind the scene and this is also an advantage using Pandas by single statement without explicitly writing loops to iterate over all elements.  By using Pandas, you would better enjoy its fast efficient yet succinct  vectorization processing instead.

As your formula is based on a condition, you cannot use direct multiplication. Instead you can use [`np.where()`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) as follows:

```
import numpy as np

df['Pow_calkowita'] = np.where(df['liczba_kon'] == 0,  df['Powierzchn'], df['Powierzchn'] * df['liczba_kon'])
```

When the test condition in first parameter is true, the value from second parameter is taken, else, the value from the third parameter is taken.

Test run output:  **(Add 2 more test cases at the end; one with 0 value of `liczba_kon`)**

```
print(df)

    liczba_kon  Powierzchn  Pow_calkowita
0            3    69.60495      208.81485
1            1    39.27270       39.27270
2            1   130.41225      130.41225
3            1   129.29570      129.29570
4            1   294.94400      294.94400
5            1    64.79345       64.79345
6            1   108.75560      108.75560
7            1    35.12290       35.12290
8            1   178.23905      178.23905
9            1   263.00930      263.00930
10           1    32.02235       32.02235
11           1   125.41480      125.41480
12           1    47.05420       47.05420
13           1    45.97135       45.97135
14           1   154.87120      154.87120
15           1    37.17370       37.17370
16           1    37.80705       37.80705
17           1    38.78760       38.78760
18           1    35.50065       35.50065
19           1    74.68940       74.68940
20           0    69.60495       69.60495
21           2    74.68940      149.37880
```

Answer (score 0):

dataframe is designed to operate with [vectorication](https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6). you can treat it as a database table. So you should use its functions as long as it's possible.

```
tdf = df                                                     # temp df 
tdf['liczba_kon'] = tdf['liczba_kon'].replace(0, 1)          # replace 0 to 1
tdf['Pow_calkowita'] = tdf['liczba_kon'] * tdf['Powierzchn'] # multiply
df['Pow_calkowita'] = tdf['Pow_calkowita']                   # copy column
```

This simplified the code and enhanced performance., we can test their performance:

```
sampleSize = 100000
df=pd.DataFrame({
    'liczba_kon': np.random.randint(3, size=(sampleSize)),
    'Powierzchn': np.random.randint(1000, size=(sampleSize)),
    })

# vectorication
s = time.time()
tdf = df                                                     # temp df 
tdf['liczba_kon'] = tdf['liczba_kon'].replace(0, 1)          # replace 0 to 1
tdf['Pow_calkowita'] = tdf['liczba_kon'] * tdf['Powierzchn'] # multiply
df['Pow_calkowita'] = tdf['Pow_calkowita']                   # copy column
print(time.time() - s)

# iteration
s = time.time()
result = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['liczba_kon'] == 0:
        result.append(row['Powierzchn'])
    elif row['liczba_kon'] != 0:
        result.append(row['Powierzchn'] * row['liczba_kon'])
df['Pow_calkowita'] = result
print(time.time() - s)
```

We can see vectorication performed much faster.

```
0.0034716129302978516
6.193516492843628
```

Answer (score 0):

**To answer the first question: "Why I can't do that?"**

The [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.iterrows.html) states (in the notes):

> Because iterrows returns a Series for each row, ....

and

> You should never modify something you are iterating over. [...] the iterator returns a copy and not a view, and writing to it will have no effect.

this basically means that it returns a new Series with the values of that row

So, what you are getting is NOT the actual row, and definitely NOT the dataframe!

BUT what you are doing is working, although not in the way that you want to:

```
df = DF(dict(a= [1,2,3], b= list("abc")))
df                 # To demonstrate what you are doing
   a  b
0  1  a
1  2  b
2  3  c

for index, row in df.iterrows():
...     print("\n------------------\n>>> Next Row:\n")
...     print(row)

...     row["c"] = "ADDED"           ####### HERE I am adding to 'the row'

...     print("\n -- >> added:")
...     print(row)
...     print("----------------------")
...     
------------------
 Next Row:     # as you can see, this Series has the same values
a    1         # as the row that it represents
b    a
Name: 0, dtype: object  

 -- >> added:
a        1
b        a
c    ADDED     # and adding to it works... but you aren't doing anything 
Name: 0, dtype: object   # with it, unless you append it to a list
----------------------


------------------
 Next Row:
a    2
b    b
Name: 1, dtype: object
                       ### same here
 -- >> added:
a        2
b        b
c    ADDED
Name: 1, dtype: object
----------------------


------------------
 Next Row:
a    3
b    c
Name: 2, dtype: object
                          ### and here
 -- >> added:
a        3
b        c
c    ADDED
Name: 2, dtype: object
----------------------
```

**To answer the second question: "Is it good way?"**

No.

Because using the multiplication like SeaBean has shown actually uses the power of
numpy and pandas, which are vectorized operations.
[This is a link to a good article on vectorization in numpy arrays](https://www.pythonlikeyoumeanit.com/Module3_IntroducingNumpy/VectorizedOperations.html), which are basically the building blocks of pandas DataFrames and Series.